# Control LaTeX expression color in ipython qtconsole

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I'm using a dark background for ipython. I would like to have sympy expressions pretty-printed with LaTeX. Problem is the current LaTeX font is black. How can I change LaTeX font colors in the ipython terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `forecolor` and `backcolor` options in `sympy.init_printing`.  For example, to print the equations in blue, use

```
In [1]: init_printing(forecolor="Blue")
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Spyder, apparently because it doesn't work when rendering using matplotlib, which it apparently falls back to when latex is not installed https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7786

Comment: After installing http://miktex.org/, I try to do this and it automatically installs some packages, including `xcolor`, and now it prints in the color I want.

Comment: This answer is for SymPy only, it doesn't change the color for other objects that define `_repr_latex_()` like Pint units.

Comment: @endolith the question should probably be edited. I believe that's what the OP was asking about (note the "sympy" tag, and the fact that this answer was accepted).